# UITextView inside UIScrollView disable textview scrolling

Tags: uiscrollview, swift2, uitextview

I have UIScrollView inside which I have UITextView, when the text size increase I don't want the textview to scroll, but the scrollview should scroll as the text size increases. How can this be achieved?

Comment: is user is inserting text in `UITextView`?

Comment: user can't edit textview.. but text is added dynamically.

Comment: Then why u are taking `UITextView`? Take the `UILabel` and it will adjust it according to the content

Comment: I have HTML string.. and if there are any links they should be clickable.

Comment: can you show me your `UIStoryboard` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: I have to work on that.. not started yet.. but this is the requirement.